# Show data from mysql database to php html using AJAX at the time on opening page

Tags: php, html, mysql, ajax

I build a function as like whenever webpage is load automatically data from MySQL database will show on my html page. I need not to click any button. But function is not working here. It giving me error. How can I fetch my MySQL database data without clicking any button or link?

```
<div class="display-area">
            
            </div>

            <?php
            if(isset($_GET['display'])){
                $q = "SELECT * FROM userpost";
                $result=mysqli_query($conn, $q);

            $sqllogin = "SELECT * FROM userpost";
            $resultlogin = $conn->query($sqllogin);
            while($rowlogin = $resultlogin->fetch_assoc()) {
            
                $pracTest=$rowlogin['id'];
            }
            ?>
            <div><?php echo $prac?></div>
            
            <?php }?>
```

AJAX code

```
 function displayFromDatabase(){
            $.ajax({
                
                type: "GET",
                async: false,
                data: {
                "display": 1
                },
                success: function(d){
                    $(".display-area").html(d);
                }

            });


        }
```

To show MySQL data at the opening of page I did that

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        displayFromDatabase();
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: @devlincarnate GET-404 error

Comment: Have you tried adding an `url` parameter to your AJAX call?  Error 404 means the resource is not found...

Comment: yeh tired too..404 was removed...file is now ok...but get no values either

Comment: Check F12 network tab and view the response from the server.